# Which parts of CRYSTALS-Kyber and CRYSTALS-Dilithium are compatible?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, implementation, lattice-crypto, kyber, dilithium

The papers CRYSTALS-Kyber and CRYSTALS-Dilithium both have been written by quite different authors. It seems that at least the key generation is very different from each other. CRYSTALS mainly seems to be a suite of algorithms based on the hardness of module lattices.

From CRYSTALS-Kyber:

> **CRY**ptographic **S**ui**T**e for **A**lgebraic **L**attice**S** – a package submitted
> to NIST post-quantum standardization effort in November 2017), a portfolio of post-quantum cryptographic primitives built around a key-encapsulation mechanism (KEM), *based
> on hardness assumptions over module lattices*.

Where the KEM part is obviously specific to Kyber, not to Dilithium

Which mathematical operations can be shared between implementations of both? What kind of percentage of these algorithms could use that shared implementation of (low level) primitives?

Comment: When I first started reading into these algorithms I was expecting that the CRYSTALS-projects were largely using the same kind of underlying implementation, but the papers don't even use the same identifiers (e.g. $\operatorname{KeyGen}$ vs just $\operatorname{Gen}$).

Comment: Inside, there are some overlapping modules.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking about looking at the ref & liboqs source code and answering myself, but I'm hoping that somebody has an answer ready. I think it would be useful for KEM and signatures to share implementation details for e.g. embedded devices and other HW implementations.

Comment: I am going through Kyber and Dilitihum, but it would take probably a few months to give a (reasonably) correct answer. :P

Comment: If you can import it into a reasonable IDE, like Eclipse for C/C++ then you should get things like method lookup and such. In that case it should be *relatively* easy to dig down and get answers. It would be a challenge, but it should not take months :)